# Strange error when updating 5.23.0 Joomla

Tags: upgrade

When i try to update my Joomla version (Windows) to 5.23.0 I get the screen to run the database upgrade utility after the question are you ready to upgrade (Yes) I get the screen with the progress-bar left at the screen but it does nothing. 
When I look at the console of the screen I see warnings as:
Laden voor het  met bron ‘http://localhost/Joomla/Joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js’ is mislukt.
(and 14 others). The URL must be with only once "/Joomla". I didn't change or save the civicrm.settings.php. But there is no double /Joomla.
What is the reason that the URL is wrong? I have tried version 5.23.1 with the same result.

Comment: can you check civicrm.settings.php if $civicrm_root is set properly?

Comment: $civicrm_root = 'C:\wamp\www\Joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm';

Comment: That is the same value as in an version 512 civicrm_settings.php. Without a backslash at the end (in the example above it is with a backslash, but i do not think it must be with a backslash, it works the same.
I think the statements are generated in CRM/CORE/Resources.php but in line 824 bower_components en 825 packages there is something done with slash and not with the backslash, that are the statements where i get the  double Joomla part.
Maybe it has something to do with an update in 5.23.0 to allow a path to be relative releas-notes/5.23.1.md.

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the lines 824 en 825 in CRM/CORE/Resources.php with a dirty solution:

$map = ['bower_components' => str_replace('Joomla/Joomla','Joomla',rtrim(Civi::paths()->getUrl('[civicrm.bower]/.', 'absolute'), '/')),
      'packages' => str_replace('Joomla/Joomla','Joomla',rtrim(Civi::paths()->getUrl('[civicrm.packages]/.', 'absolute'), '/')),
    ];

It can not be the real solution but the site is now working and i have just completed succesful the database-upgrade. Maybe only a problem with sites on Windows.

Comment: The problem is solved in version 5.23.4